# What does "E/USNET: USNET: appName:" mean?

Tags: android

I'm using android studio, everything works fine but I get this: **E/USNET: USNET: appName: fr.me.myapp** when I run the app.
So my question is simple, what does that mean ?
I don't think that's a problem but I can't find anything on the internet so I was curious, thanks.
Edit: here is the whole stacktrace

```
$ adb shell am start -n "fr.apgames.veuja/fr.apgames.veuja.SplashScreenActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 28166 on device 'samsung'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/r.apgames.veuj: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
E/USNET: USNET: appName: fr.apgames.veuja
D/ProcessState: Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument
D/ActivityThread: setConscryptValidator
D/ActivityThread: setConscryptValidator - put
D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication()++ app=fr.apgames.veuja
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10564; state: ENABLED
W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~YFkivQlevnQ42gxYdE4UFg==/fr.apgames.veuja-m2_7QeRBzBPIP4mOIK91dQ==/base.dm': No such file or directory
W/ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~YFkivQlevnQ42gxYdE4UFg==/fr.apgames.veuja-m2_7QeRBzBPIP4mOIK91dQ==/base.dm': No such file or directory
D/nativeloader: Configuring classloader-namespace for other apk /data/app/~~YFkivQlevnQ42gxYdE4UFg==/fr.apgames.veuja-m2_7QeRBzBPIP4mOIK91dQ==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~YFkivQlevnQ42gxYdE4UFg==/fr.apgames.veuja-m2_7QeRBzBPIP4mOIK91dQ==/lib/arm64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/fr.apgames.veuja
V/GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE Developer option for 'fr.apgames.veuja' set to: 'default'
V/GraphicsEnvironment: App is not on the allowlist for updatable production driver.
D/LoadedApk: LoadedApk::makeApplication() appContext.mOpPackageName=fr.apgames.veuja appContext.mBasePackageName=fr.apgames.veuja
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication() --
D/OpenGLRenderer: RenderThread::requireGlContext()
D/AppCompatDelegate: Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
I/DecorView: [INFO] isPopOver=false, config=true
I/DecorView: updateCaptionType >> DecorView@2ca0824[], isFloating=false, isApplication=true, hasWindowControllerCallback=true, hasWindowDecorCaption=false
D/DecorView: setCaptionType = 0, this = DecorView@2ca0824[]
I/DecorView: getCurrentDensityDpi: from real metrics. densityDpi=640 msg=resources_loaded
W/r.apgames.veuj: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/r.apgames.veuj: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
D/OpenGLRenderer: RenderThread::setGrContext()
I/MSHandlerLifeCycle: isMultiSplitHandlerRequested: ignored. pkg=fr.apgames.veuja parent=null callers=com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.setVisibility:4295 android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity:5301 android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute:54 android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute:45 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState:176 
I/MSHandlerLifeCycle: removeMultiSplitHandler: no exist. decor=DecorView@2ca0824[]
I/DecorView: notifyKeepScreenOnChanged: keepScreenOn=false
```

... There's more but that's just the app running

Comment: Could you paste the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @JustSightseeing I pasted it